# REST API routing standards for complex objects

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

For example, lets say I have the following model that is used to update a person's details via Web API:

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Are there any standards that dictate how I should structure the API routes for this endpoint when posting this data from the browser?

Would I need to have:

```
[Route("people/person/{personId}")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SavePerson(int personId, Person personDetails)
```

Or should I just use:

```
[Route("people/person")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SavePerson(Person personDetails)
```

If **PersonId** is 0 then it is assumed that this is new data and hence a new record will be created, otherwise an update will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

BAsed on my experience the best method to post (or PUt) complex object is:

```
[Route("people/person")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SavePerson([FromBody]Person personDetails){

// then you can check here if model is valid and if id is ont set ..then call insert CRUD method or UPDATE  method..something like:

 if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

 return Ok(personDetails.Id == 0 ? _repository.insert(personDetails) : _repository.update(personDetails));

}
```

Hope it Help you ..

p.s other REST method for what you described is `PATCH`

Comment: If you're being strict about it, `POST` is always for creates, and `PUT` or `PATCH` for updates. PUT is used to completely replace a resource, and PATCH to do change some fields/attributes of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required specify the '[FromBody]' in post action. Rest api send's the data in form body  only,if it is complex object.

```
[Route("people/person")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult SavePerson(Person personDetails){

        // then you can check here if model is valid and if id is ont set ..then call insert CRUD method or UPDATE  method..something like:

         if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

         return Ok(personDetails.Id == 0 ? _repository.insert(personDetails) : _repository.update(personDetails));

        }
```